# Repeating a <select> menu multiple times with a SQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create a page which has a  menu repeated 20 times on the page.  The options from my  menu will come from a SQL query.

This works for the first  menu, but I am getting empty options on the others.

So I have this in my PHP section:

// query and display records for Riders menu

```
$q4 = "SELECT id, fname, lname
    FROM riders
    ORDER BY lname, fname ASC"; 
    $r4 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q4);
```

And in my echo I have this:

```
<!-- Input results -->';
    for($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++) {
        echo '<tr>
        <td><select id="rider" name="rider[]">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['lname'] . ', ' . $row['fname'] . '</option>';
        } // End of WHILE loop

        echo '</select></td>
        </tr>';
    }   
    echo '<tr><td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Results" /></td></tr>
```

Why wouldn't my WHILE loop work properly on each iteration of the FOR loop?

Comment: You want 20 copies of menu with same set of options?

Comment: Yes.  There are other options in the menu (I abbreviated my code a bit), but I want to select one of those names to go with each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $options = '';    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          $options .='<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['lname'] . ', ' . $row['fname'] . '</option>';
    } // End of WHILE loop 

    for($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++) {
          echo '<tr><td><select id="rider" name="rider[]">';
          echo $options;        
          echo '</select></td></tr>';
   }
```

try this..

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Thanks.  It looks like you moved my while loop outside of my FOR loop.  Why does that work, but having the WHILE inside the FOR doesn't work?

Comment: probably because the fetch array has already reached its limit which cause it to stop looping.

using this approach is much faster than what you're trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
 <?php 
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id, fname, lname FROM riders ORDER BY lname, fname ASC");
echo '<select name="country" class="country">
<option selected="selected">--Select Name--</option>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
 echo '<option value="'.$row['fname'].'">'.$row['fname'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```